# IOS celForRowAtIndexPath loop logic?

Tags: objective-c, ios, if-statement, for-loop

I suppose I need a better understanding how and when the iteration of this method works.  The code below is in my cellForRowAtIndexPath method and it works fine. it's purpose is to check the inList (Array) and if what ever index values it finds Gray out the Text of a uiTableView Cell; however when I edit and delete a cell from my tableView (located two viewControllers away) the code does not update from gray to black even though the index integer is no longer in the array of values to gray out.....Doesn't this method get called every time I load this page or is there a flaw in my loop logic  ?   Many Thanks.

```
if ([inList count] > 0) {

       if([[[inList objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"myIndex"] count] > 0) {


           NSArray *myIndexList = [[inList objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"myIndex"];
           NSLog( @"data from INDEX !!!!!!!! %@", myIndexList);

               for(int n=0; n<[myIndexList count]; n++)
               {
                   if(indexPath.row == [[myIndexList objectAtIndex:n] integerValue])
                   {
                       cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
                   }

               }

         }


   }
   else{
       cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
   }
```

Comment: are you removing the value from "inList" then called [{your table} reloadData] when this viewController reappears?

Comment: yes in viewWillApear and in viewDidAppear [self.tableView reloadData].  It updates new entries in the entries in the inList ....it turns those gray ....but nothing when I remove an entry from that same list, just stays gray after the integer has been removed

Comment: are you calling "reloadData" after you remove the entry?

Comment: yes...assuming that viewWillApear gets called every time I load the ViewController.  I remove the entry on page 3 and write it to a plist....so when I go back to page 1 where this code and the tableview in question exists ...reload should get called again in viewWillAppear